# Restart the PC remotely

Tags: windows, networking

I am connecting to my workspace 's PC (window xp) in my home using the company VPN. I can ping it successfully after connecting to the VPN .Is it possible to restart this PC remotely by using some scripts /tools ?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541

Answer (score 6):

you can use shutdown.exe.  just type shutdown /? at a command prompt and it will contain all the necessary switches.

Something like this should work:

```
Shutdown.exe /r /f /m \\computername
```

Comment: … and don't forget that the help for the `shutdown` command is *not* `/h`. That's hibernate. Someone does that at least once a quarter ;)

Comment: HAH... i forgot that one.

Comment: Really? That is such crappy UI! Sysadmins need some UX love too...

Comment: @MartijnHeemels Use `shutdown /i` for an interactive GUI.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels I don't care that much about UI... just a shutdown command. It's quick, it's easy and more importantly... it works.

Comment: To be clear, with UI I don't mean a GUI. I mean an CLI command structure that is predictable, with obvious inputs and provides clear output. Using `/h` for an action that could bite you, instead of for the standard help action, is just bad design. It should always be safe to ask for help in the way that is common on the platform, and several variations.

Comment: using `/h` as a switch for CLI tool help is not common in windows. `/?` is.

Answer (score -3):

Read up on the command sc.exe. On my Win7 PC it is at C:\Windows\system32\sc.exe.

Comment: How exactly is `sc` going to help the OP?

Comment: Good point, I was too quick to answer. I used to use sc to restart services (VNC), not the whole PC.

Comment: Who said anything about the OP using VNC?